# sequential numbering of rows

Tags: sql, row

I have to customize a SQL view to be able to perform a system integration test. One table keeps track of the transactions and the LINE ITEMS per transactions (for example, transaction 2 has three items, so there are three consecutive rows corresponding to the same transaction number) What I need to accomplish is to get a column where I keep track of the number of items for THAT transaction, always starting from 1 for each transaction.

For example, the first column is `TransactionNumber` and the second is `DesiredOutput`:

```
1                    1
1                    2
2                    1
2                    2
2                    3
3                    1
4                    1
4                    2
```

ETC...

I know how to number consecutive rows on the WHOLE table, but I cannot find any reference to this numbering that depends on a value on another row.

Comment: Please add your current query so we can start from there

Comment: what kind of sql is? mysql? mssql? other?

Comment: and the type and version number of database (eg: oracle 8.4, mysql 5 etc)

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server 2005+ and Oracle you can use the following:

```
SELECT TransNumber, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Transnumber ORDER BY Something) [DESIRED COLUMN OUTPUT]
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks Lamak, I will try it as soon as the system is ready to test.